# Cannot find module "rxjs/observable" on build. IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, rxjs, angularfire2

I am working on an ionic app that is using AngularFire2. But when I push up the code to ionic i get a build error:

```
 ionic-app-scripts build


[22:28:07]  typescript: src/providers/sermon/sermon.ts, line: 4 
            Cannot find module 'rxjs/observable'. 

       L3:  import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
       L4:  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';

[22:28:07]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[22:28:07]  Error: Failed to transpile program 
Error: Failed to transpile program
```

I don't know what is going on... Could someone point me in the right direction for this?

Comment: It's 'rxjs/Observable'. Voting to close for typo. Decent IDEs add imports for you.

Comment: I suspect it may be due to a platform issue, specifically Mac OS X, and its old non-case-sensitive filesystem.  On my Mac, both VS Code and Webstorm include Observable with the lower-case path, and it builds fine locally.  Once I try to build on a non-mac system it fails, until I go back and change the path case.

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple typo mistake, pls replace that,

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; // 'O' is capital in 'rxjs/Observable'
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new RxJs 6 it would be

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```